# Enable/Disable NFC with ADB command

Tags: android, shell, adb, nfc

Is there any way to disable/enable `NFC` via `ADB` shell commands?

I found one answer [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2535580).

What I tried from the above link:

```
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 5

# Disable NFC
service call nfc 4
```

but it's not working.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why no one has posted this already

`svc nfc <enable|disable>`

Works perfectly

Edit: Requires > Android 6.0

Comment: Works on Oreo (8.1)

Comment: Worked on Android 7

Comment: Works on Android Q (10)

Answer (score 5):

*# Disable NFC*

service call nfc 7

Verified for Android 8.0

Cheers!

Comment: And enable for Android 8.0: `service call nfc 8`

Answer (score 3):

In your DDMS of eclipse or using logfilter or any runtime log capturing tool, you need to get the process ID of your NFCService. Then you can kill or stop that process by giving the process ID.

Comment: Not a good idea, also this will kill the service and makes NFC inaccessible from the API point of view, the NFC chip will still be active. There is no process to shut it down after all.

Answer (score 1):

System services' method codes may vary with `Android` versions. Therefore, before making a service's method call browse the `AOSP` sources.

Below is a summary of the `NFC`'s enable/disable calls up to `Android` 5.1.1. Also keep in mind that (in the sources)

```
int FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION  = 0x00000001
```

,i.e. equals to `1`.

**Android [4.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable) - Android [5.1.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable)**:

```
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 5
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 6
```

**Android [4.0.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable) - Android [4.3.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3.1_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable)**:

```
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 4
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 5
```

**Android [2.3.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable) - Android [2.3.7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable)**:

```
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 18
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 19
```

**Android [2.3.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable)**:

```
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 20
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 21
```

**Android [2.3.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/nfc/INfcAdapter.java#INfcAdapter.Stub.0TRANSACTION_disable)**:

```
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 13
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 14
```

---

To check the status of the `NFC` service use the `dumpsys` command:

```
dumpsys nfc
```

Comment: Note that If device is rooted the commands may need to be called as `su` (`adb shell su`).

Comment: What is the solution for the OS version >7?

Answer (score 1):

For Android 12:

```
# Disable
service call nfc 8

# Enable
service call nfc 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 6
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 5
```

please check [here](http://www.slideshare.net/yossigruner/android-adb-51289739) in slide no 32

Answer (score 0):

For Android Version > 7, please use following -

```
# Enable NFC
service call nfc 7
# Disable NFC
service call nfc 6
```

Verified on  7.1.1... Should work for atleast 7.x