# ADB command Enable/Disable NFC for MOS

Tags: android, shell, nfc

I'm trying to create a batch file to test for NFC on/off, so I went to the following post to figure out how to programmatically turn NFC on/off using adb command on MOS device:
[Enable/Disable NFC with ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993117/enable-disable-nfc-with-adb-command)

Turning on the NFC worked using the following command : adb shell service call nfc 6.

However, turning off NFC isn't working. I tried the following commands:
adb shell service call nfc 0
adb shell service call nfc 1
adb shell service call nfc 2
adb shell service call nfc 3
adb shell service call nfc 4
adb shell service call nfc 5
adb shell service call nfc 7
adb shell service call nfc 8
adb shell service call nfc 9

but none of them worked. "adb shell service call nfc 5" worked in L-OS device, but not in MOS device. How can I turn off NFC using adb command in MOS device? What changes did Google make?

Comment: Android M OS. https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found this on XDA. Maybe you should give it a try.

**NFC POWER OFF**

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/nfc-power/nfc_power 0<&- &>/dev/null 2>&1
```