# Native Android Device > turn off/on NFC with ADB

Tags: android, adb, nfc, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to turn off/on (disable/enable) NFC with ADB for non-rooted Android device with v 6.0.1 version or higher?
i tried many stuff but it wont work for me.

Stuff i tried are:

Via ADB:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_toggleable_radios bluetooth,cell,wimax,nfc
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.airplane_mode_toggleable_radios

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE

adb shell settings put global radio_nfc 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.radio_nfc

adb shell settings put global AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS

adb shell settings put global NfcAdapter 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.NFC_adapter

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios cell,bluetooth,nfc,wimax
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:'bluetooth,nfc,wimax' --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"
```

also:

```
adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_radios 
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/global --projection name:value --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'" 

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios "cell,nfc,wimax"
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:'cell,nfc,wimax' --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"

adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios "cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax"
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:'cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax' --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"
```

After restarting the device i can turn ON the airplane-mode with ADB but the nfc does NOT go off.
As i turn ON the airplane-mode on the native device (quick settings OR settings) it does go off!

Another one i tried is:

List the running services with:

```
adb shell service list
```

there you can read that nfc is running at number 9 " nfc: [android.nfc.INfcAdapter] "

try to disable with

```
adb shell pm hide com.android.nfc
```

does not work and throws:
*Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.*

or:

```
adb shell pm grant EXAMPLE.android.services android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
adb shell pm grant EXAMPLE.android.services android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

-

following is working on devices up to Android 5x:
[Enable/Disable NFC with ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993117/enable-disable-nfc-with-adb-command)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with [Enable/Disable NFC with ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993117/enable-disable-nfc-with-adb-command)

On android Marshmallow (6.0.0 or 6.0.1)

<s>Disable</s>

`service call nfc 5`

Enable

~~service call nfc 6~~

Edit:

This doesn't seem to disable permanently, rebooting re-enables the service

Found the real answer!

`svc nfc <enable|disable>`